# Graceful shutdown for Spring Cloud Application

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to setup an environment with Docker containers in which I run Spring Cloud Applications. I am using Zuul as gateway and Eureka for service discovery.

Now, what I am trying to do, is when I send SIGTERM signal through docker stop command and the Java process is shutting down, I need to catch somehow this event, put the service OUT_OF_SERVICE in Eureka registry, then wait some time, and then shut it down, as mentioned by @spencergibb here: [Make Spring Cloud app to wait for eureka clients to remove it before fully shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710131/make-spring-cloud-app-to-wait-for-eureka-clients-to-remove-it-before-fully-shutt?rq=1)

Do you happen to know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use actuator's shutdown endpoint /actuator/shutdown to gracefully shutdown spring cloud application, consider doing that in an JVM shutdown hook.